# Asymptotics for a series of products

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, infinite-product

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Define the following functions for $x>0$:
>   $$f_n(x):=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}$$
>
> 1. Show that the function
>      $$f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_n(x)$$
>      is well defined for $x>0$. Calculate its value in $1$.
> 2. Study the function $f(x)$ and give asymptotic estimates for $x \to 0^+$ and $x\to +\infty$.
> 3. Prove that the following equivalence holds:
>      $$f(x)=e \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!}$$

I am having a hard time proving the equality in the third point. What I have done for now:

$\textbf{Part 1}$

Using the ratio test,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{x+k}}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{x+n+1}=0$$
 the series converges for $x>0$. The value of the function in $1$ is

$$f(1)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)!}=e-1$$

$\textbf{Part 2}$

First of all, $f$ is positive for every $x>0$. Its monotonicity is immediate: if $x_2>x_1$,

$$\begin{align} \quad \qquad \frac{1}{x_2+k}<\frac{1}{x_1+k} \end{align} \\
  \implies f(x_2)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x_2+k}\leq\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x_1+k}=f(x_1)$$

The general term of the series $f$ must be zero, because it converges; hence in an interval $[M,+\infty)$ with $M>0$

$$||f_n(x) ||_{\infty}=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{M+k}$$
$$\implies \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}||f_n(x)|| \text{  is convergent}$$

so the series is uniformly convergent on every interval of the type $[M,+\infty)$.

$f$ is asymptotic to $\frac 1x$ for $x\to +\infty$: in fact

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}= \lim_{x\to \infty}  x\left (\frac{1}{x}+ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}\right )= 1 $$

because the series converges in a neighbourhood of $+\infty$.

In a neighbourhood of $0$, the function acts similarly: we can notice that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} x\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}=\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\left (\frac{1}{x}+ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}\right )=  \lim_{x\to 0^+}  1 + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}$$

but $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}$ converges in $x=0$ and is continuous, so the limit is

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1+  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}=e$$

hence $f \sim \frac{e}{x}$

Monotonicity and limits of this function imply that $f$ is a bijection of $(0,+\infty)$ in itself.

$\textbf{Part 3}$

I have tried to manipulate the sums: writing a single fraction instead of the product does not seem to work: it leads to

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{x(x+1)}+\dots=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\sum_{h=0}^{n}\prod_{k=0}^h(x+k)}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}$$

It does not seem very familiar, even dividing it by $e=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=f(1)$ Another idea that came to mind was to use the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) series and the Cauchy series product on the **RHS**: it leads to

$$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{(x+j)j!}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{l=0}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{k-l}}{(x+k-l)l!(k-l)!}$$

Things seem as complicated as before. Integrating or derivating $f(x)$ term by term would require to know a general form for the integral/derivative of $f_n(x)=\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}$: it does not appear impossible to find it, but I think it would not be of great practical use; moreover, the series does not converge uniformly on  the whole interval $(0,+\infty)$. The same goes for the series on the **RHS**. Working backwards, I thought of finding its integral/series on the interval $[M,+\infty)$ : I obtained

$$\int \left (e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!} \right ) dx =e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \int \frac{(-1)^n}{(x+n)n!}  dx=e\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}  \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\log(x+n)+C $$

I can't get far from here, and I am not even sure if what I have done is correct.

> **Question**: Are the two first parts correct? What could be a good way of proving the equality in the third part?

Comment: It looks like you have a small typo in your demonstration of monotonicity for part $2$. The terms $f(x_2)$ and $f(x_1)$ seem to be in each other's places. Also I believe you could replace $\leq$ with $<$, though that's not important.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Thank you for your observation. Got it fixed!

Comment: I think your derivation of $f(1)$ is off by $1$, you sum over $1/(n+1)!$, thus resulting in $f(1)=e-1$.

Comment: @mlk True. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the remaining third point, I would use the formula
$$f_n(x)=\frac1{n!}\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{n}dt.$$
Exchanging the order of summation and integration, we get
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=\int_0^1 t^{x-1} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1-t)^n}{n!}\right)dt
=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}e^{1-t}dt=\\&=e\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^k t^{x-1+k}}{k!}dt=e\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(x+k)k!}.
\end{align*}

Comment: It's obvious once one knows that $\beta(x,n+1)=n!{\prod_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{x+k}}$. I did not think about it. Good answer, thank you very much!

Comment: @bharb I didn't know if we were allowed to use beta function. And if we weren't, then that formula could be shown by induction.

Comment: Just one doubt: the series does not appear t converge uniformly on $(0, +\infty)$ because $||f_n||=sup_{x \in (0,+\infty)f_n(x)= +\infty}$ as $\lim_{x \to 0}f_n(x)=+\infty$; the exchange of order between the series and the integral can thus be done in every interval of the kind $[M,+\infty)$; how can I justify it over the whole domain?

Comment: @bharb It comes from $\frac1x$ factor in each $f_n(x)$. If you consider instead $xf(x)$ this problem will disappear.